# MySql/Rails created_at timestamp

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I needed to import a hugh `csv file` into my `rails app`, and creating records through my model was taking a really long time. So, I decided to import the file directly using `mysql`. By doing this, the `created_at` and `updated_at` column for all records is `"0000-00-00 00:00:00"`.

Should I expect any consequences/side effects arising from this in the future?

Answer (score 0):

If you test against the columns, you will get weird values. If you just ignore them, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the column to created instead of created_at.